Pymongo, via flask-pymongo won't load some images. Flask 2.0.2, flask-pymongo 2.3.0, app engine, Werkzeug 2.2.0
I have recently been running into trouble uploading photos on my website, and I've found this error literally printed in my logs, rather than being logged as an error. It's all happening in the guts of flask, and not my code, so I'm a bit stumped. Any guidance on where I should be looking to fix things would be helpful:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/srv/app/views.py", line 605, in view_media_file
    return app.mongo.send_file(filename)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_pymongo/__init__.py", line 206, in send_file
    response.set_etag(fileobj.md5)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/werkzeug/sansio/response.py", line 498, in set_etag
    self.headers["ETag"] = quote_etag(etag, weak)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 888, in quote_etag
    if '"' in etag:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Edit: So, I realized the problem is that something changed between pymongo 3 and pymongo 4 that breaks something along the way. If I downgrade to pymongo 3, everything works fine again, but the previously uploaded photos are still not salvageable, so I'm expecting that the problem is in that section of code.

You need to figure out where etag is set and why it has a value of None instead of being a string.  You could potentially do this quote_etag(etag or "", weak).

So, I realized the problem is that something changed between pymongo 3 and pymongo 4 that breaks something along the way. If I downgrade to pymongo 3, everything works fine again, but the previously uploaded photos are still not salvageable, so I'm expecting that the problem is in that section of code. I'll update the question with this information.

this error means that you tried to iterate something that Pymongo couldn't find. But if you can provide the code it would be better to understand and detailed logs.
But here is the solution to your possible problem
@app.route("/your-route")
def yourroute():
    data = myCollection.find({'type':'post'})
    output =[]
   
    # add just this, it is easier than a if else statemet
    if data == None:
        data = []
    for d in data:
        output.append(data['title'])

    return {'out':output}

Edit based on your needs but this is probably the issue you're facing
